# TP5100 battery charging IC PCB design burning out

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, tp5100

It's been almost 4 days now trying to diagnose this design of mine. I ordered 5 PCBs from JLCPCB with this design. Here is my schematic, and the schematic from the component datasheet.

It's an [TP5100](http://toppwr.com/uploadfile/file/20230304/6402f53e7e8d9.pdf) battery charging IC, in my case configured for a two cell, 8.4 V pack. I followed every step of the datasheet and its diagram, it's basically a copy, and now it's the third IC that just completely burns out when I connect the charger.

I'm charging with 12 V, just like the datasheet specifies. I hooked up to a lab bench power supply and it was working perfectly at about 8-9 V. When I reached close to 10 V the current went way up and just burned the IC.

I really don't know what I did wrong in this design. There's only one thing that I changed from the datasheet's diagram. I used a non-Schottky diode for this design; it recommends an SS34, and I used an SM4007PL, which is rated for 1 A, which is my max charging current. I don't know if the difference between a Schottky and this regular diode I chose would lead to this kind of failure.

My schematic:
[image: My schematic]

TP5100 datasheet's schematic:
[image: TP5100 schematic]

Diagram is from above reference datasheet.

Comment: What is pin 17 in your schematic?

Comment: Does your SM4007PL diode work at 400 kHz ?  Reverse Recovery Time trr
 IF=0.5A,IR=1.0A  IRR=0.25A is ~ 3us.  SS34 is for use in low voltage high-frequency inverters, freewheeling, DC/DC converters, and polarity protection applications.

Comment: Please don't use pointless net names to join nodes that are virtually physically next to each other and please don't use a hard-to-read black background on your schematic.

Comment: The pin 17 is just the center ground of the chip. About the diode: I gotta be honest I did not think of that, I just checked the datasheets but could not find anything about the reverse recovery current nor the recovery time. In the SS34 it says "Ultrafast reverse recovery time", but wont specify any numbers. The SM4007 has IF = 1A and IR = 10uA, but again not any info about the reverse recovery characteristics.

Comment: Unfortunately there’s a few critical components in that circuit and the pcb layout is critical as well. It’s just not a matter of throwing whatever component looks like it might work at it. So using a standard rectifier instead of a Schottky diode is the first mistake.  What inductor did you choose? What voltage for the 10uF ceramics?

Comment: Hey Kartman. I'm not by any means an engineer or electronics experts. I like to design my own PCBs for some projects and I always just follow the recommendations from the datasheet. The diode was really a very stupid mistake because of time and space constraints hehe. Now I can see how that would impact the function. About the caps, they are all 25V X5R. The inductor is a 10uH, 1.3A rated, and lsat of 1.66A.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I do not know why there are ANY close votes, or a downvote. Gabriel is a new member, has asked a good question about a design issue. The information provided is good. Their design decisions are what is being asked about and should not form the basis for down voting or close voting.

Comment: Down voting and VTC are members prerogatives. But I am regularly surprised at  how a core group of members seem to push VTC beyond what I (fwiw) consider anything like reasonable. In this case, as I've commented above, I see no reason for the VTCs or the downvote. The OP has made two (apparently) bad design decisions - neither of which are grounds for either action - especially for a new member. || Explanation of VTCs and downvote would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your schematic you show CS (pin 13) connected to VREG.
This places the IC in a 2 cell (8.4V) mode.
For single cells CS should be left open circuit.
It is not certain that this, rather than or as well as the diode selection, is causing the problem, but if this does not destroy the charger IC it will very certainly destroy the battery.

**___________________________**

[Datasheet](http://toppwr.com/uploadfile/file/20230304/6402f53e7e8d9.pdf), page 9  - CS (Pin13): Lithium ion status
selection input terminal.

- CS pin
  high input voltage level (VREG) will
  make TP5100 the lithium-ion
  battery charging state until 8.4V
  and enters shutdown state.
- If CS
  pin is floating, TP5100 becomes
  4.2V lithium-ion battery charging
  status until 4.2V, and enters
  shutdown state.
- Low input voltage
  level shutdown TP5100. CS pin can
  be driven by TTL or CMOS voltage
  level.